# Searching for a key using va_arg in C

Tags: c

The first number taken as argument is the key which is to be found in the numbers following it. My code ignores the first number and and stores the second number in `key`, and also fails to return a correct result when I add a zero at the beginning of the argument to fix choosing the second argument.

The code:

```
int search(int n, ...)
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl,n);
    int key,flg=0;
    key=va_arg(vl,int);
    printf("key %d\n",key);
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        int x=va_arg(vl,int);
        if(key==x)
        {
            printf("FOUND!\n");
            flg=1;
            break;
        }
    }    
    if(flg==0)  
        printf("NOT FOUND!\n");
    va_end(vl);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    if(argc<=1)
    {
        printf("No arguments passed!");
    }    
    else
    {
        int key=atoi(argv[1]);
        search(0,key,34,45,12,78,11,4,90,89,54,63,7,98,43);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you invoke the function a bit like `search(10, value, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);`?  What goes wrong when `value` is `1`?  `10`?  `20`?  Since you only print something and always return `0`, why are you bothering with a return type other than `void`?  Or should you be returning the position at which the value was found?

Comment: Please give examples of exactly how you're calling the function, what you expect it to do, and what it actually does.

Comment: updated it, even if I input key such as 90(for example), it returns not found

Comment: Your call sets `n` in the function to `0`, so the loop never executes, so the value in `key` is never found.  You probably shouldn't be looping `for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)` — you should probably be calling `search(13, key, 34, 45, 12, 78, 11, 4, 90, 89, 54, 63, 7, 98, 43);` and looping `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` (as is customary in C).  Or you should pass `15` and start your count at `2` (and still use `<` and not `<=`).  But this is a pretty implausible function — OK as an exercise in using variable argument list, but otherwise implausible.

Comment: The function signature should probably be `int search(int n, int key, ...)` so you don't need to use `va_arg()` to find key.  But that isn't immediately critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is close to your code.  I altered the error handling in `main()` — error messages should be reported on `stderr`, not `stdout`, and should end with a newline.  The `main()` function loops over multiple arguments so a single run can test multiple values.

I also changed the call so that the number of arguments in the variable list is given as `n`, the first argument. There is no point in always returning `0` so I changed the function to return `void` (nothing).  Alternatively, you should return `flg` so the calling code can tell whether the value was found or not.  With the function returning no value, this yields the code:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void search(int n, ...)
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, n);
    int key, flg = 0;
    key = va_arg(vl, int);
    printf("key %d\n", key);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x = va_arg(vl, int);
        if (key == x)
        {
            printf("FOUND!\n");
            flg = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flg == 0)
        printf("NOT FOUND!\n");
    va_end(vl);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s key\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        int key = atoi(argv[i]);
        search(13, key, 34, 45, 12, 78, 11, 4, 90, 89, 54, 63, 7, 98, 43);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When run (source `va71.c`, program `va71`), I get:

```
$ va71 89 78 34 43 199 -1
key 89
FOUND!
key 78
FOUND!
key 34
FOUND!
key 43
FOUND!
key 199
NOT FOUND!
key -1
NOT FOUND!
$
```

which is what I'd expect.

Here's a reorganized version which reports the position where the key is found.  There's no printing in the search function — keep I/O separate from the searching.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int search(int n, int key, ...)
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, key);
    int flg = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x = va_arg(vl, int);
        if (key == x)
        {
            flg = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    va_end(vl);
    return flg;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s key\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        int key = atoi(argv[i]);
        printf("key %d: ", key);
        int rv = search(13, key, 34, 45, 12, 78, 11, 4, 90, 89, 54, 63, 7, 98, 43);
        if (rv < 0)
            printf("not found\n");
        else
            printf("found at index %d\n", rv);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ va71 89 78 34 43 199 -1
key 89: found at index 7
key 78: found at index 3
key 34: found at index 0
key 43: found at index 12
key 199: not found
key -1: not found
$
```